# Apply indices in looped function

Tags: r, function, loops, cross-validation, threshold

I am attempting to apply indices in a looped function to create a new dataframe to essentially manipulate cross-validation results. I am having a problem with actually using those indices to apply into my looped function.

The error occurs at `oppo` which is where I try to extract the indices for each of the folds. `oppo` should represent all the indices of Folds 1-5, except not of Fold i.

Reproducible Example to create dataframe

```r
#data
attach(PimaIndiansDiabetes)
data=PimaIndiansDiabetes

#create training and testing sets
set.seed(101) 
sample <- sample.int(n = nrow(data), size = floor(.7*nrow(data)), replace = F)
train <- data[sample, ]
test  <- data[-sample, ]

#create simple RF
ctrl <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, savePredictions = TRUE)
rf_model <- train(diabetes ~., data=train,
                  metric="ROC",
                     trControl=ctrl)

#reformat the dataframe of interest
cv_dataframe <- rf_model$pred %>% filter(mtry==2)
cv_dataframe$Resample <- sub("Fold", "", cv_dataframe$Resample)
```

In my looped function I would like to set i = 1:5, and get the `rowIndex` for everything but `i`. So for the dataframe below,

```
head(cv_dataframe)

  pred obs   neg   pos rowIndex mtry Resample
#1  neg neg 0.540 0.460        1    2        1
#2  neg pos 0.544 0.456       11    2        1
..
#3  neg neg 0.926 0.074       5     2        2
#4  pos neg 0.182 0.818       16    2        2
..
#5  neg neg 0.764 0.236       17    2        3
#6  neg neg 0.780 0.220       26    2        3
```

after I extract `rowIndex` for `Resample==1`, I would like to apply `!rowIndex` to `train`and get an output of a dataframe that is `train` but only indices that match `Resample` 2 through 5. Then I would like to ,  predict on `train` for only the `rowIndex` where `Resample==1`.  This is what I have tried:

```r
cv_performance <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(sort(unique(cv_dataframe$Resample)), 
function(i) { 
  
  #extract indices where Resample is opposite of i
  oppo <- cv_dataframe$rowIndex[!cv_dataframe$Resample==i] ##HERE IS THE ERROR
  
  
  #ask it to paste df of folds 2-5 
  print(train[oppo,])
  
  #now look at results where test fold is opposite of oppo
  
test_prob_cv <- as.data.frame(predict(rf_model,                   #original model
                                        newdata = train[!oppo,], #data of leftover fold
                                        type = "prob"))


  
  })))
```

But I think the issue is with `oppo` because I cannot use it as a list of indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `oppo` are numbers to remove those row index we have to use `-` (`!` is used to invert logical values). Try :

```
library(caret)

result <- lapply(unique(cv_dataframe$Resample), function(x) {
  oppo <- cv_dataframe$rowIndex[cv_dataframe$Resample!=i]
  as.data.frame(predict(rf_model,newdata = train[-oppo,], type = "prob"))
})
```